# TextArea value set by JQuery causing Model.IsValid to be false

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I have a file browser and a TextArea in the same Kendo Grid cell.  The user clicks the file browser, selects the file, and using JQuery, I set the value in the textarea to be the file path selected.  This textarea is bound to the model which will then be sent back to the controller and written to the database when saved.  I have everything working as expected, except when I click save, and the code hits the breakpoint I set in the controller, the Model.IsValid value is false which causes nothing to write to the database.

If I click into the TextArea and type some more text after selecting the file, then save, everything works just fine.  For some reason, if I try to save with just using the file browser and filling out all other required fields and never actually clicking into the TextArea, the Model is invalid and nothing is written.  See code below:

View (the field in question is 'BackupLocation'):

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<FooModel>()
      .Name("gFoo")
      .Columns(columns =>
         {
             columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); });
             columns.Bound(x => x.Type).EditorTemplateName("TypeTemplate");
             columns.Bound(x => x.RequestedBy).Title("Requested By");
             columns.Bound(x => x.BackupLocation).Title("Backup Location").EditorTemplateName("FileBrowserSelect");
             //...Other columns
          })
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .PageSize(50)
              .Model(model =>
                {
                   //Model info
                })
                 .Create(create => create.Action("InsertFoo", "Foo"))
                  // Read Update Delete follow
       )
 )
```

Editor Template:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m, new {@id = "BackupLocation", @class = "k-textbox", @rows = 10, style = "Width:100%; overflow:hidden;"});
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
     .Name("LocationSelector")
     .Multiple(false)
     .ShowFileList(false)
     .Events(events => events.Select("onSelect");
)
```

JavaScript onSelect function:

```
function onSelect(e){
      var l = $("LocationSelector").val();
      var s = $("BackupLocation");
      s.val(l);
}
```

Controller Method:

```
public ActionResult InsertFoo([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, FooModel fooModel)
{
   if(fooModel != null && ModelState.IsValid)  //this is where I leave my breakpoint.  ModelState.IsValid is false so the rest of the code is skipped
   {
       //skipped code
   }
}
```

I have redacted a lot of the irrelevant code for the sake of time (I can't copy and paste from the machine I'm doing the work on) but I think this gets the idea across.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

***UPDATE***
This is the model that I'm using, forgot to include that

```
public class FooModel
{
   public int ID {get; set;}

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select a Type")]
   public string Type {get; set;}

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select a Requestor")]
   public string RequestedBy {get; set;}

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide file location")]
   public string BackupLocation {get; set;}

   //...Other fields
}
```

Comment: In your EditorTemplate you are creating a textarea from your own model, is this correct or it's typo? @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m,).

Comment: When you break point on `ModelState.IsValid` can you put `ModelState.Values` into the watch window, expand it out and tell us what is the contents of the Errors array?

Comment: @padhraic The only error is actually the field validation error that I put because I want the field to be required.  It doesn't show up when I'm submitting the form, but it is showing up in the model when I look at it at the breakpoint in the controller.

Comment: @Padhraic if I comment out the field validation in my model and try submitting, it does submit and gets past the breakpoint, however the value that I set with the field selection still doesn't save to the DB